# html2Canvas - Returned canvas is empty

Tags: html2canvas

I am trying to implement html2Canvas v 1.0.0-rc.1 in my Angular 7/Ionic 4 project.

The issue I have is when I try to get the canvas of a simple div, the return canvas is emptied and nothing is appended to my destination div using *.appendChild as per the documentation.

For debugging I console log the return canvas where it looks like this:

```
<canvas width="0" height="0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></canvas>
```

Below is my code and console logs. I've tested in Safari 12 and Chrome 74. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
    <div id="destination">
      Destination - Html Canvas to Append to This
    </div>
    <div id="cover">
        Source - Hello World
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**Javascript/Component**

```
printTest(): void {
    let element = document.getElementById("cover");
    console.log('Source Element', element);
    html2canvas(element).then((canvas) =>{
      console.log('Console Canvas', canvas)
      var destination = document.getElementById('destination');
      destination.appendChild(canvas);
    });
}
```

**Console Logs**
[image: Console Logs]